# Using distance_of_time_in_words in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a start month (3), start year (2004), and I have an end year (2008). I want to calculate the time in words between the start and end dates. This is what I'm trying and it's not working..

```
# first want to piece the start dates together to make an actual date
# I don't have a day, so I'm using 01, couldn't work around not using a day
st = (start_year + "/" + start_month + "/01").to_date
ed = (end_year + "/01/01").to_date

# the above gives me the date March 1st, 2004
# now I go about using the method 
distance_of_time_in_words(st, ed)
```

..this throws an error, "string can't me coerced into fixnum". Anyone seen this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just concatenate strings and numbers in Ruby. You should either convert numbers to strings as **mliebelt** suggested or use [string interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation) like that:

```
st = "#{start_year}/#{start_month}/01".to_date
```

But for your particular case I think there is no need for strings at all. You can do it like that:

```
st = Date.new(start_year, start_month, 1)
ed = Date.new(end_year, 1, 1)
distance_of_time_in_words(st, ed)
```

or even like that:

```
st = Date.new(start_year, start_month)
ed = Date.new(end_year)
distance_of_time_in_words(st, ed)
```

See `Date` class [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-new) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the context in which you are calling the method is one that knows the methods from [`ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html), you should change the following:

```
# first want to piece the start dates together to make an actual date
# I don't have a day, so I'm using 01, couldn't work around not using a day
st = (start_year.to_s + "/" + start_month.to_s + "/01").to_date
ed = (end_year.to_s + "/01/01").to_date

# the above gives me the date March 1st, 2004
# now I go about using the method 
distance_of_time_in_words(st, ed)
=> "almost 3 years"
```

So I have added calls to `to_s` for the numbers, to ensure that the operation `+` is working. There may be more efficient ways to construct a date, but yours is sufficient.